# is there a way to return a list with other lists in it with this code?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I need to write this code where I take a list that has lists in it and takes in the ints in those lists and divide them by 2 and then return a new list that contains the lists with the divided ints

Here's what I came up with. I just can't seem to get a list that contains lists in it

```
def div_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    mat2=[]
    for i in range(len(mat)):
        for j in range(len(mat[i])):
            a = mat[i][j]//alpha
            mat2.append(a)
                
    return mat2 
mat1 = [[2, 4], [6, 8]]   
print(div_mat_by_scalar(mat1,2))
```

this prints `[1,2,3,4]` but I want `[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Comment: don't use `for index in range(len(iterable))` use `for item in iterable:` instead

Comment: The easiest and maybe _not a good idea_ way is to use recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append to a nested list, not the main list.

```
def div_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    mat2=[]
    for row in mat:
        row2 = []
        for el in row:
            a = el//alpha
            row2.append(a)
        mat2.append(row2)
    return mat2
```

Or use list comprehensions:

```
def div_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    return [[el//alpha for el in row] for row in mat]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're appending every element to the list. [Bamar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817158/2422776) is great if your `mat` is always two dimensional, but if you want to generalize this function to any number dimensions, you may want to adopt a recursive approach:

```py
def div_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    result = []
    for elem in mat:
        if isinstance(elem, list):
            result.append(div_mat_by_scalar(elem, alpha))
        else:
            result.append(elem // alpha)

    return result
```